# Add new record using django autocomplete light

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-autocomplete-light

I use autocomplete-light quite extensively in my app to do foregin key searches and all works really well. Now i got a request from my users, they would like to have the possibility to add new records when they cant find what they need in the autocomplete field.

For example if the user register a new service request and tries to look up the requesting customer and the customer does not exist in the system. In this case the user would like to have a button to click beside the autocomplete field. A popup should show where he/she can enter the customer data than click save and the new customer should exist in the database and in the autocomplete field when they come back to the service ticket entry screen.

So i had a look at "Add another popup outside the admin" in the documntation and it almost does what i want, it adds the new record to the db but in the example it than redirects to an edit view where id like to come back to the screen where the add button was clicked and have the new added foregin key record displayed in the autocomplete field, is this possible ? is there any examples around where this is already solved ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve it or did you find how to approach to this workflow?

Comment: Nope i gave up and used an other aproach instead, sorry